# Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function when bundling with WebPack 4

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am importing some library

```
import { connect } from '@captaincodeman/redux-connect-element';
```

into my TypeScript 4 Web Component and using it like

```
export class AppRouterElement extends connect(store, LitElement) {....}
```

and then simply `yarn build` (Yarn 2). Build succeeds with no errors, but at run-time I'm getting 
`Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`

When digging into compiled JavaScript I see output of

```
let Sr = class extends (Object(wr.connect) (fn, vr)) {....}
```

which seems missing a comma. If I add that comma in-place, application seems working as expected.
If I run the same source build with Rollup i have no runtime error.
Which relevant WebPack (or mby TSC) configs I should look into/for. I have no idea about the correct name of this issue, so I stuck to google it properly.

Comment: Ok. Seems i got closer. I just copied that module locally and imported as local utility library and no more errors.

Answer (score 0):

i got a similar error, when import like this

```
import start from './modules/App.jsx';
```

it just like this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at eval (index.js:4)
at Module../src/index.js (main.d806e840d36f0916cf01.js:589)
at __webpack_require__ (main.d806e840d36f0916cf01.js:20)
at eval (webpack:///multi_(:8080/webpack)-dev-server/client?:2:18)
at Object.0 (main.d806e840d36f0916cf01.js:624)
at __webpack_require__ (main.d806e840d36f0916cf01.js:20)
at main.d806e840d36f0916cf01.js:84
at main.d806e840d36f0916cf01.js:87
```

after spending a few of my life~, i found i missed braces...
just below i fixed

```
import { start } from './modules/App.jsx';
```

that is not the corresponding answer, hoping show some tip for you~